# Using Rasterize tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, rasterization

I've been following the steps in the book "An intro to using gis in marine biology, supplementary workbook seven".

I'm trying to create a presence-absence map by turning the data layer of dolphin sightings in the North Sea to a raster layer, however I'm not able to select the "PRESENCE" attribute field from the list of existing attributes in the attribute table.

Is there something I've missed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue with QGIS 2.14.9 on Windows64 now. Rasterize does not accept integer field. It only shows fields with Real numbers... Strange... I am almost sure previous versions worked well with integer values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Possibly a bug.**

Did some tests using QGIS 2.18.2 and found that if you use the *Rasterize (vector to raster)* from the menubar (i.e. `Raster > Conversion > Rasterize (vector to raster)`), the tool only seems to read the following field types:

- Real
- Integer
- Integer64 (**but only if the length is <10**)

---

However, if you run the same tool from the *Processing Toolbox*, it doesn't seem to filter out the field types (it even lists date fields). So best solution is probably to do what [@Kazuhito](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84455/kazuhito) has suggested.

Comment: Running it through Processing Toolbox works! ...and, without having to create another field just to avoid the issue. wow.

Comment: @Kazuhito - Interesting! My guess would be that the interface of the tool when running from the menubar doesn't include `integ64` fields but no such filter is used in the interface when running from the processing toolbox. But I always used the method you described ;)

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the Rasterize tool didn't accept Real, Integer, or Integer64...It only worked when I set the precision to be '1' and called the field type a Decimal number (Real). Your method also works too, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just a workaround, not a solution - please change the type of the field from **Integer** (1) to **Real** (1.0).

One way would be `Field Calculator | Create a new field | Output field type as Decimal number (real)`, and set `Precision` to 1 (or anything).

It seems Rasterize function of some recent versions does not accept Integer fields. (Tested: QGIS 2.14.9, 2.14.11 and 2.18.3 on Windows64. Not sure if it applies to other platforms.)